# How to add special characters in url in angular 15

Tags: javascript, angular, url-rewriting, angular15

I'm upgrading an old application written in Angular JS to latest Angular 15. The migration is smooth but facing problem in urls. Actually our survey url exists like this below and it is different for every survey.
https://some-domain.com/#/77RqxKxiEdXDccBB8S3iahYS9MB4cGqQR9G6XciZKR0+U=

Ass you can see, the url contains '+' and '='. But when I'm using this url in my angular 15 application, it is replacing the special characters and especially removing the '=' from the url.

But in DB, this encrypted id is being stored as an unique identifier and using this only all the details are fetched from DB.

The problem is that I cannot change the url as many previous surveys have been sent to customer with that url.

Any help will be really appreciated.

I've tried using some of the help found from google like using URIencode or help from this url
https://stackblitz.com/edit/allowing-angular-4-routes-to-pass-special-charact-ebpsmt?file=src%2Fapp%2Furl-serializer.service.ts

but it is still not working as the '=' is still getting missed from the url.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario URL is getting encoded only in browser.
In your case you can still fetch all the details from DB based on token. You can fetch original token from "ActivatedRoute" of angular router component.

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
  private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
 ){}

ngOnInit() {
  // this will fetch original (decoded) token for you
  const token =  this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('token') 
};
```